# How to scale a list by a weight?

Tags: python, statistics

Let's say I have

```
values = [0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50]
```

and I want to scale each element by a **weight**, so values get smaller (or bigger) faster the further they are from the mean. That is, to get «small numbers» (numbers below the average) bigger, and «big numbers» (numbers over the average) smaller.

Let's pretend the average is 1, then:

```
scale(values) -> [0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 1, 1.5, 4, 8, 12, 20]
```

Values over the average would **decrease** faster the further they are (2 to 1.5, but 50 to 20), while values under the average would **increase** faster the further they are (0.5 to 0.8, but 0.1 to 0.6).

I tried searching for «how to normalize data», but such answers scale all values equally. For example

```
scaled = [(i - min(values))/max(values) for i in values]
```

Also, I *need* to control the weight in which the values are scaled.

Comment: Could you provide any attempt you made on your own as well as the desired output of the above?

Comment: @Ian: one way is to square all the values: values smaller than one will get smaller, values larger than 1 will get larger, rate of change depends on distance.

Comment: use the logarithmic value?

Comment: Please provide an exmaple, of what you wish to achive/obtain eventually. maybe you can apply "normalization" with constumizing weights. maybe:  ln = 6, coeff = [1/(1 + abs(l/2 -i)) for i in range(6)] take a look at numpy's array too, it may help you.

Comment: Added some examples.
Also, I am having problems with the square approach, as small numbers get smaller. I intend to get «small numbers» (below average) bigger, and «big numbers» (over average) smaller.

Comment: Bigger you mean closer than the avergage ? Smaller -> closer than the average ? Could you provide the "real" use case ? I have to go now, but this will help others. thx for your quick updates, it' pleasant to help people like this :).

Comment: Made a correction, should be easier to understand now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps, you are looking for a min-max scaling, this lets you specify arbitrary lower and upper bounds.

With numpy, the implementation is simple:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50])
l, h = .6, 80
```

```
(arr - arr.min()) / (arr.max() - arr.min()) * (h - l) + l

array([ 0.6       ,  0.75911824,  1.23647295,  2.03206413,  3.62324649,
        8.39679359, 16.35270541, 32.26452906, 80.        ])
```

With python, the procedure is similar; compute the mean and standard deviation, and perform this process element-wise.

Comment: How can I control the scale in which the elements are scaled using this method?

Comment: @IanFieldhouse if you want to choose arbitrary min and max values, you should instead consider min-max scaling.

Comment: @IanFieldhouse For example, `(arr - arr.min()) / (arr.max() - arr.min()) * (80 - .6) + .6`

Answer (score 0):

From @coldspeed answer :

If you want further values to get away further you should use a function that looks like a parabol, like the square (x-x**2) function.

```
In [1]: import numpy

In [2]: vls = numpy.array([0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 1, 3, 8, 15, 40, 80])

In [3]: arr = vls

In [4]: 
   ...: (arr - arr.mean()) / np.std(arr) 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-f9f164a1e884> in <module>()
      1 
----> 2 (arr - arr.mean()) / np.std(arr)

NameError: name 'np' is not defined

In [5]: np = numpy

In [6]: 
   ...: (arr - arr.mean()) / np.std(arr) 
Out[6]: 
array([-0.62731596, -0.62338705, -0.61945814, -0.61160032, -0.53302212,
       -0.33657662, -0.06155292,  0.92067457,  2.49223857])

   ...: ((arr - arr.mean()) / np.std(arr)) ** 2
Out[8]: 
array([  3.93525316e-01,   3.88611416e-01,   3.83728389e-01,
     3.74054953e-01,   2.84112582e-01,   1.13283823e-01,
     3.78876235e-03,   8.47641671e-01,   6.21125309e+00])
```